# Particular page in PDF with lagging scroll

Tags: c#, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have generated a pdf using wkhtmltopdf and .NET. It works kind of as expected. However, a particular page in the document is making the pdf reader (tried both Chrome and Acrobat Reader) lag/freeze. The document is not particularly large, just 2.5MB.

That perticular page (fourth in attached file) is a relatively javascript- and markup heavy (in it's web vversuion that is).

What could be causing this slow scrolling/lag/freeze behavior?

Link to file: http://www.filedropper.com/proof635454306396959111

Comment: The PDF page content streams in your document look very complicated and convoluted considering its fairly simple output, and the stream for page 4 furthermore is very long. This quite likely is the cause why PDF renderers have a hard time rendering it. The convoluted and complex structure very likely is due to its complex source. If you need to transform one format to another (here HTML to PDF), it is generally a good idea to use lean, tidied-up source. wkhtmltopdf experts (which I am not) might give you more practical hints if you give some more information on the nature of the HTML source.

Comment: The web page is fairly heavy on the javascriptside, but the generated markupoutout is fairly simple.
What would be a good approach to investigate/debug the pdf stream. Any good tools? (@mkl)

Comment: I looked at it using RUPS, but there are other PDF browsers around, too. To understand the contents, you need some understanding of the PDF specification, though.